# Changing home folder for users

Tags: home

I have a question regarding changing the home folder for a user on the system.
I was thinking I could do something like:

```
new_folder_name="$2"
user_name="$3"
mkdir /home/$new_folder_name
usermod -d -m /home/$new_folder_name/$user_name
```

This unfortunately did not work and now  I feel kinda lost. Anyone have some advice on how to do this?

I used `mkdir /home/$2
chown $3:$3 /home/$2
chmod 700 /home/$2
usermod --home /home/$2 $3`

instead, which works, but it prints chown: invalid group:username:username afterwards, why is that?

Comment: Please define "did not work". What happened? What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

At first you must create path `/home/$2/$3`. 
You may execute, for example, `mkdir -p /home/$2/$3`
Then you need run `chmod username:username /home/$2/$3`
After that you may run `usermod -d -m /home/$2/$3`
I think is nessessery to run `chown 750 /home/$2/$3`

Comment: I dont get the username:username part, do I change that to the username of the user that I wish to move, for example: chmod $3:$3 /home/$2/$3 ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed a space in `usermod`, you should also quote your variables. You will also have to move the data (probably instead of creating the empty directory).

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in `usermod`

Try as

```
usermod -d /home/$new_folder_name -m $user_name
```